# Can / Should I add kotlinc.xml to my version control ignore file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, version-control, kotlin

Somewhere in the process of setting up a Java project in IntelliJ IDEA (2017.1.2) a file in the `.idea/` directory called `kotlinc.xml` showed up. I do nothing with Kotlin, but the file is there with contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="KotlinCommonCompilerArguments">
    <option name="languageVersion" value="1.1" />
    <option name="apiVersion" value="1.1" />
  </component>
</project>
```

This seems some generic configuration, but I can imagine some project-specific (and not just my-local-IDEA-specific) configuration of Kotlin is stored there. So, in general, can this file be ignored when sharing the project under version control (e.g. Git), i.e., not committing it and publishing it somewhere online? Or should it be ignored?

Comment: The bug causing this file to be generated for projects that don't use Kotlin is fixed in Kotlin 1.1.2, which is bundled in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never submitted anything from `.idea` directory.

If you use modern build system like [*Gradle*](https://gradle.org/) or [*Maven*](https://maven.apache.org/) there is no need to submit such metafiles because IDEs like Intellij IDEA or Eclipse can successfully extract such metadata from dependencies / properties.

Mostly, IntelliJ will ask you to override existing properties in `.idea` folder.

After importing Gradle / Maven project IntelliJ creates its own `.idea` directory with configurations and properties.

I prefer to keep my project as clean as possible (sources, build (gradle, maven) files, CI, README). Fortunately, Java allows us to make **portable** sources / projects so we should not waste this chance :)

Comment: Seconded, you should never commit to version controls something that can be generated by using the development tools, especially when the files in question will never be a part of the finished product. If you find new users pulling your repository and having trouble, then maybe you missed some files or might need to re-evaluate a few files you decided to not version control but otherwise, do not version it.

Comment: +1. IMO, projects should not contain IDE dependencies unless the dependency is for some reason required.

Comment: Makes sense, devs should be able to choose their own IDE setup and let build tools handle all the metafiles. Thanks for the clarification @ answerer and previous commenters!

Comment: I am not sure this is such a good suggestion. We've been versioning some (notice that not all) files in the .idea folder - one very important one being "codeStyleSettings.xml", as we want to have consistent code formatting in our team. Most of the other files are not worth versioning, sure, but it does make sense to have at least the aforementioned file under the version control.

Comment: @NeverwinterMoon what about just exporting code style?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov Exporting surely works - but it means you have to import and, probably, re-import/re-export if the style changes. If you version that file, on the other hand, all the newly updated code formatting will automatically work (if you have selected Editor > Code Style > Scheme = Project in the settings). In addition to that file, we version settings for some of the IDEA 3rd-party plugins we use, they are stored in different *.xml files in the same folder. Exporting and importing all of those is a hustle for sure.

Comment: I'm with NeverwinterMoon.  Sometimes IDE configuration files support team norms.  This answer gives a strong philosophical reasoning, but those sorts of rules should always be weighed against effective processes. The code style example is very important and shouldn't be dismissed.  Do you want your new team member to read a wiki about where to find the teams code styling file, or do you want code styling to be as automated as possible.  One more point on that example, allowing code styling to version against the codebase they govern is another value add.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer.  It doesn't inform us as to why the file exists, how it works, and/or whether or not it is something that should be versioned along with the source code.  Instead, it provides an opinion about best practices in regards to a set of files that have a very wide range of reasons of existing.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. There are particular development situations where you absolutely want project and ide files present. If your entire development team has settled on a given toolset and you want to share particular project specific files, why not? Obviously you don't want to store user specific configuration files but project wide files are fine.

Comment: Quote from Jetbrains documentation: "we recommend sharing the .idea/codeStyles directory via VCS"
https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/09/kotlin-1-3-rc-is-here-migrate-your-coroutines/

Answer (score 6):

You should not add this file to your version control ignore file. We have this file checked in, as it contained relevant JVM target information. This is in line with the [official Jetbrains sharing recommendation](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems), which states:

> Here is what you need to share:
>
> - All the files under the .idea directory [...]

kotlinc.xml is not stated as an exception to this rule.

Additionally, the gitignore templates from [github](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore) and [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/api/intellij) do not list this file, so it should be checked in.